Recaptcha v3 generar token en backend
Estoy implementando Google recaptcha V3 en mi sitio web desarrollado en Blazor webassembly y api rest como backend, todo funciona como se espera, se obtiene el token en el frontend y se envía al backend para ser validado. La seguridad es administrada por medio de JWT.
Ahora, estoy desarrollando un servicio de windows el cual hace login y obtiene el JWT para hacer peticiones al api rest, desde que se implementa Google recaptcha las peticiones desde el servicio de windows están pasando por medio del recaptcha, como el token del frontend se obtiene por medio una librería de Javascript no he encontrado como hacer el mismo proceso de obtener el token pero sin javascript y enviarlo en el login en el mismo servicio de windows.
¿Alguna idea?.
